# Firebase 5: Ambiguous use of 'observeSingleEvent'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What is wrong with the way in which I am making this call on a Firebase reference?

I keep getting error ***Ambiguous use of 'observeSingleEvent'***

```
func updateFcmTokenOnChats(userID: String, fcmToken: String) {
    let ref =  DDatabaseRReference.users(uid: userID).reference().child("chatIds")
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snapReceived) in
        print("someCode")
    }  
}//end of updateFcmTokenOnChats
```

Here is an explanatory image of the error message:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the complete log error?

Comment: As in the initial question, the error is "Ambiguous use of 'observeSingleEvent'"

Comment: the issue is the *let ref =* line ending with .reference. I would suggest storing Firebase as a class var and assign it like this *self.ref = Database.database().reference()* and and then when you want to access Firebase just do this *let ref = self.ref.child("users').child("some_uid").child("chatIds")* followed by *ref.observe...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to solve the compiler confusion using:

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapReceived) in
        ...
})
```